# Replace Regex Symbols + Blank Space

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

There is any way to make a regex to replace symbols + blank space?

Im using:

```js
const cleanMask = (value) => {
  const output = value.replace(/[_()-]/g, "").trim();
  return output;
}

let result = cleanMask('this (contains parens) and_underscore, and-dash')
console.log(result)
```

Its it right?

Comment: You get to decide what "right" entails. "Symbols" could mean pretty much anything. What is your specification, exactly? If you want to include blank spaces, you probably need `\s` or a blank space though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will replace all occurrences of characters _, (, ) and - with an empty string and then trim() whitespace from the beginning and end of the result.

If you want to remove ALL whitespace, you can use the whitespace character class \s instead of trim() like this:

```
const output = value.replace(/[_()-\s]/g, "");
```